# How to do backup of development branches with Gerrit?

Tags: git, backup, gerrit

I'm using Gerrit to manage my git repository. Patches are sent to Gerrit server and merged into the git repository when they are approved. However, often a feature takes some time to develop and the developer wants to keep a backup of the code under development. The obvious solution is to push the branch directly to Gerrit, but then https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=1986 prevents me from submitting this branch to review.

A possible hack is to remove the remote branch when I want to submit it to review. A second one is to rebase the remote branch and update change IDs when I want to submit it to review.

How do you handle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [draft reference](https://review.typo3.org/Documentation/access-control.html#references_magic)? It is useful when a code should backup, without listing it as an open patchset. Then if the code is ready it can be published. My suggestion is to avoid reviewing more then one commit. More commits/changes harder to be efficient on a review.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to fix this is to amend the commit. This will create a new commit that can then be pushed to another branch.

```
git commit --amend
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

Comment: You are supposing a specific case where you have only one commit in your development branch. In the generic case, imho you should use rebase to amend all commits, as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Ok, I guess I misunderstood your question. My interpretation was that you wanted to push a change to a different branch, not a whole series of changes. But why do you need to change the Change-ID?

Comment: I need to change the commits hashes because Gerrit does not allow me to submit commits for review which are already pushed to Gerrit. See the link to Gerrit issue tracker I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Actually, it is not related to the Change-ID. You can cherry-pick changesets to different branches and have the same Change-ID. This is actually a nice feature as it will allow you to track which branches have received that particular change

Comment: I am not sure if Gerrit checks if commit hash or change ID already exists in its remote repository to assert if a commit may be submitted to review. Regardless of which "primary key" is used, rebasing an existing remote branch just to be able to submit it to review is annoying. The purpose of my question is to identify if there are better alternatives.