# gerrit - understanding replication or create a backup

Tags: git, backup, gerrit

we've a running gerrit 2.14.2 with mysql backend.

Now we wan't to mirror/backup it.

I don't understand the replication feature. Is it necessary to setup a full gerrit/git in the same config as the source instance?

The other mentioned way would a DB dump an replay to the other machine and a rsync from the git repository?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do backup of development branches with Gerrit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703552/how-to-do-backup-of-development-branches-with-gerrit)

Answer (score 1):

To use the replication feature you need to install/config the [replication plugin](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-plugins.html#replication). it's part of the core plugins so it is packaged within the Gerrit war file and can be installed running a Gerrit initialization (java -jar gerrit.war init). The plugin will mirror all changes to another Gerrit server which will be used as warm-standby backups or a load-balanced mirror.

If you're only interested in backup maybe running rsync/mysqldump is a better/simple solution. Unfortunately it's necessary to stop Gerrit before performing the backup to make sure the filesystem and the database are synchronized. You need to execute something like this:

```
service gerrit stop
rsync -avh --delete GERRIT-SITE/ SOME-LOCATION
mysqldump --host=DB-HOST --port=DB-PORT --user=DB-USER --password=DB-PASS DB-DATABASE > SOME-LOCATION/gerrit-dump.sql
service gerrit start
```

You can optimize the time Gerrit will be stopped by running rsync first (with Gerrit up), stop Gerrit and then execute rsync again (the second execution will be very fast).

Comment: OK I'm running the gerrit replication in a test enviroment.

One problem was, that I've to import the rsa ssh key in the ~/.ssh/known_host, now it replicate new projects on the destionation.

One additional question: How to import the changes on the destination automatic? I see the new projects/changes only after restart the gerrit daemon.

Thank you so far.

Comment: Do you mean you need to restart Gerrit everytime you have changes or the replication doesn't work? This is weird...

Answer (score 0):

OK I was wrong, I haven't restart the destination gerrit daemon.
When I got in a Project I see the changings, only in the list view a reload in the browser doesn't refresh the icons.

Thank you for support.

Gregor